# Вывести значения из многомерного массива foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, вывод

Выкладываю весь код, просто на всякий случай, проблема в самом конце

```
// Дан массив $cars. Состоящий из трех машин со следующими данными: Мерседес - 10000 руб, BMW - 9999 руб, Автобус - 20000 руб.
    $cars = [
        [
            'name' => 'Мерседес',
            'price' => 10000,
            'colors' => [],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'BMW',
            'price' => 9999,
            'colors' => [],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Автобус',
            'price' => 20000,
            'colors' => [],
        ],
    ];
    
    // 3. Для каждой машины заполните поле colors. В этом поле должны хранится все возможные варианты цветов для этой машины, при чем для каждого этого цвета, есть своя надбавка к стоимости (разная для разных машин)
    // Создайте массив colors с цветами доступными для каждой машины. И случайным образом выберите из этого массива по 3 цвета для каждой машины. Эти цвета добавьте в массив $cars в поле colors. Для каждого цвета также укажите случайную надбавку к цене - случайное число от 0 до 100
    // Выведите итоговый массив $cars c помощью функции var_dump и убедитесь в его правильности.
    $colors = ['красный ', 'синий ', 'черный ', 'серый ', 'сафкари ', 'градинуойд ',];
    foreach ($cars as $key => $car) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            $cars[$key]['colors'][] = [
                'name' => $colors[rand(0, count($colors) - 1)],
                'extra' => rand(0, 100),
            ];
        }
    }
    var_dump($cars);
    
    // 4. Каталог автомобилей.
    // А теперь выведите весь каталог автомобилей в виде:
    // "Купите автомобиль {} цвета {} всего за: {} руб"
    // вместо {} поставьте соответственно: название автомобиля, цвет, стоимость в этом цвете.
    foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
          foreach ($value['colors'] as $color) {
            var_dump('Купите автомобиль ' . $cars[$key]['name'] . ' цвета ' . $cars[$key]['colors'][$key]['name'] . 'всего за: ' .  ($cars[$key]['price'] + $cars[$key]['colors'][$key]['extra'])  . ' руб'); 
           } // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ КАК НАДО
    }
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ КОДА:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Мерседес"
    ["price"]=>
    int(10000)
    ["colors"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "синий "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(32)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(15) "красный "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(66)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "синий "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "BMW"
    ["price"]=>
    int(9999)
    ["colors"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "синий "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(91)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(21) "градинуойд "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(10)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(21) "градинуойд "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(79)
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Автобус"
    ["price"]=>
    int(20000)
    ["colors"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "синий "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(97)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "черный "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(43)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "черный "
        ["extra"]=>
        int(28)
      }
    }
  }
}
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Мерседес цвета синий всего за: 10032 руб"
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Мерседес цвета синий всего за: 10032 руб"
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Мерседес цвета синий всего за: 10032 руб"
string(99) "Купите автомобиль BMW цвета градинуойд всего за: 10009 руб"
string(99) "Купите автомобиль BMW цвета градинуойд всего за: 10009 руб"
string(99) "Купите автомобиль BMW цвета градинуойд всего за: 10009 руб"
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Автобус цвета черный всего за: 20028 руб"
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Автобус цвета черный всего за: 20028 руб"
string(102) "Купите автомобиль Автобус цвета черный всего за: 20028 руб"
```

От каждой машины выводит только 1 цвет и складывается цена машины (price) и надбавка к цене за цвет (extra), но в каждой машине по 3 цвета, как вывести остальные 2 цвета, я же ему говорю ходить по ключу вот тут $cars[$key]['colors'][$key]['name'] а именно [$key]['name'], почему он берет только 1 элемент а остальные 2 игнор? Как это вывести в моем стиле вывода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во внутреннем цикле можно обращаться к $color

```
foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['colors'] as $color) {
        var_dump('Купите автомобиль ' . $cars[$key]['name']   
                  . ' цвета ' . $color['name'] 
                  . 'всего за: ' .  ($cars[$key]['price'] + $color['extra'])  . ' руб');
    } 
}
```

или делать как во внешнем - получать ключ и значение - и строить ссылку с этим ключом

Comment: Большое спасибо!